# What if I use #! instead of # in href of anchor tag <a>?

Tags: html

I have used #! in href of a tag in my website. It does not throws the user on top of the page if he/she clicks the link. But my question is, is it legal?

```
<a href="#!">Click here</a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="#">Click here</a>
```

Comment: Isn't it " !# " ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It seems your goal is to create something that the user can click on in order to trigger some JavaScript and you don't want side effects (like navigating to the top of the page).

> is it legal?

- It is **not** semantically correct. Links should be links.
- It is a hack: You are linking to the element with `id="!"` and depending on the error recovery that happens when that element doesn't exist.
- It is allowed under the rules of what constitutes *valid* HTML.
- It is probably OK according to the various bits of accessibility legislation about the work which don't generally care if something works without JavaScript

---

The correct way to present a clickable control which exists only to bind JavaScript to is to use a button.

```
<button type="button">Click here</button>
```

You can apply CSS to make it look however you like though, so don't let *"But it I want it to look like a link"* stop you.

---

A more robust approach would be to use a server side fallback (i.e. a form submission or a link) and to cancel the default behaviour of the control by calling the `preventDefault` method of the event object.

---

Further reading:

- [Everyone has JavaScript, right?](http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html)
- [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement)
- [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with

```
<a href="#!">Click here</a>
```

It means you are asking the browser to navigate to the element with `id="!"`, when the user clicks on `Click here`. Element with `id="!"` probably does not exist on your page, so nothing happens.

There are a number of legitimate reasons why you want this:

- The page where you want to link does not exist, because you have not written it yet, and you prefer navigation to fail silently, instead of showing an ugly Error 404 page.
- You want to assign a JavaScript action to the click at a later date, and you want to be sure that this link looks like exactly the same as all the other links on your page.

However, there are other ways to achive this. The most common is

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Click here</a>
```

It does not rely on the error recovery that happens when an element doesn't exist, but it is not perfect. What happens if the user disabled JavaScript, or even worse, when an overprotective firewall displays a huge warning message?

Another way could be:

```
<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault()">Click here</a>
```

which is neither shorter, nor better than the previous one, and also depends on JavaScript.

Now the other one:

```
<a href="#">Top of the page</a>
```

is completely different. It navigates to the top of the page. It is simple, legal, and often used to do exacly that.

Answer (score -1):

If your goal is to create something clickable in order to trigger some JavaScript function, then another way to achieve that is:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('Hello World!');">Execute JavaScript</a>
```

- It will execute JavaScript code when the user will click the link without refreshing or scrolling the page.
- It is the best practice to link JavaScript.

**Complete Example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <a href="javascript:alert('Hello World!');">Execute JavaScript</a>
</body>
</html>
```

For more details, see [How to link to a JavaScript (HTML5 a href script)](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_href_script)