# FontAwesome icon fa-plus not visible

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I tried to add FontAwesome icon "fa-plus", but it is not showing.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
 <span class="table-add float-right mb-3 mr-2"><a href="#!" class="text-success"></a><i
                                          class="fas fa-plus fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `aria-hidden="true"` property?

Comment: Yes I tried, but it didn't work

Comment: your code works fine if you correctly included the fonts. If not then you are missing that part

Comment: Could you show complete HTML

Answer (score 0):

Your HTMLhave errors: (two "< /a>")

```
  <span class="table-add float-right mb-3 mr-2">
           <a href="#!" class="text-success">
           </a>
             <i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
           </a>
   </span>
```

Replace with this:

```
        <span class="table-add float-right mb-3 mr-2">
           <a href="#!" class="text-success">
             <i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making a mistake there. You need to remove the extra anchor  closing tag for it to work. Good luck.

Comment: Also, what did you use href='#!'' ? Just asking for my knowledge.

Comment: Refer this post bro-->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41394896/what-if-i-use-instead-of-in-href-of-anchor-tag-a

Answer (score -1):

To add font awesome + icon, use "`fa fa-plus`"

For Example :

```html
class="fa fa-plus"
```

Comment: Try using span instead  i.